# Excel - Match Cells and Show Value of Cell to the Right

Tags: excel, excel-match

I need a function to match the value entered into `C1`, to Search `A:A`, but show the value in the cell `B:B` (to the right).

The valve will be seen in `D1` (where the function will be entered).

Comment: VLOOKUP is what you want.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you would want either [`Vlookup()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) or [`Index/Match`](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/using-index-match/). [What have you tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: so I guess no one cares about the valve in the title

Answer (score 1):

Here is a typical *VLOOKUP()* solution:

```
=VLOOKUP(C1,A1:B20,2,FALSE)
```

[image]